# How to make Windows Form App in Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, forms

I'm very new to software development. My current project is to make a simple form app, and the internet suggested me to use Windows Form Application. But I'm using Macbook Air, and in my visual studio I can't find the preset. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: do you mean you cannot find **create new windows forms project template**?

Comment: yes, somehow i can't find it :( Does the operating system for visual studio matters?

Comment: i think so. because winform and wpf are windows only technologies.

Comment: i see, thanks for the help